# How to integrate .NET application in QGIS using Python?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, .net

In our company we have developed a .NET application that's now integrated with 3 different GIS platforms. Now we would like to make it work with QGIS but we need some help on getting started. I've been thinking of using callbacks and I've looked at this **[posting](http://planet.qgis.org/planet/user/7/tag/mapinfo%20programming/)** on NathanW's blog but I can't make it work in QGIS.

Any ideas?

Comment: That is MapInfo related stuff that isn't going to help you with QGIS.

Comment: I know clearly that it is MapInfo related stuff but my idea was to use the techniques - let MapInfo be replaced by our .NET application and let the python code run in QGIS

Comment: So you want to embed you .NET application into QGIS?  But still have parts of it in Python.

Comment: I want to integrate the .NET application in a way that it can get access to selected vector elements - among other things. As far as I see it - a Python plugin is the best way to integrate it but I don't know how.

Comment: Maybe IronPython?